# How to find out which row was updated in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have three tables in PostgreSQL: customers, services and bought_services. It's one to many relation with linking table, so there are foreign keys in the third table referencing primary keys in first two. There's a primary key in each table. In customers table I have `charge` column, in services there's `tax_percents` column and in bought_services there are columns `quantity`, `without_tax`, `tax` and `total`. I want to write a trigger, that after `quantity` column update would update all the `without_tax` etc. columns and also customer's `charge` column. I wrote this so far:

```
CREATE FUNCTION updateValues() RETURN TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
UPDATE bought_services SET
        without_tax = quantity * (SELECT services.net_price FROM bought_services LEFT JOIN 
            services ON bought_serices.service_id = services.id), 
        tax = without_tax * (SELECT services.tax_percents FROM bought_services LEFT JOIN 
            services ON bought_serices.service_id = services.id) * 0.01, 
        total= without_tax + tax ;

        UPDATE customers SET
        charge = SELECT SUM(total) FROM bought_services LEFT JOIN customers ON 
            wykupione_uslugi.customer_id = customers.id WHERE bought_services.customer_id = ?
    end;
$BODY$

CREATE TRIGGER UpdateBoughtServicesValues AFTER UPDATE ON bought_services
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE updateValues();
```

I don't really know what should I type instead of `?` that is, how should I tell postgres that I want to sum up the total amounts of all customer's services for which I updated the `quantity` field of one of them.

Comment: That is not a valid trigger code for Postgres.

Comment: I tried to use my knowledge from MySQL, so could you provide more details?

Comment: Corrected code, is it correct now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike MySQL Postgres has two different types of triggers: one called for each row (as MySQL) and statement level triggers.

In a row level trigger the row that is updated (or inserted) can be directly accessed using the record `new`.

So as far as I can tell, your trigger should be something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION updatevalues() RETURN TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
declare 
   l_net_price decimal;
   l_tax_percent decimal;
BEGIN

   SELECT services.net_price, service.tax_percents
     into l_net_price, l_tax_percent
   FROM services 
   where service_id = new.service_id;

    new.without_tax := quantity * l_net_price;
    new.tax := without_tax * l_tax_percent;
    new.total := new.without_tax + new.tax; 

    UPDATE customers 
       SET charge = (select SUM(total)
                     FROM bought_services 
                     where bought_services.customer_id = new.customer_id)
     where id = new.customer_id;
end;
$BODY$;
```

I optimized it a bit, to only run the select for the tax calculation once.

---

Unrelated, but: this kind of calculation in a trigger is typically not such a good idea. The golden rule of thumb in the design of a relational database is to not store data that can be derived from existing data. This kind of aggregation should only be done in very rare cases. Otherwise I would simply aggregate those number whenever I need them. I would only do stuff like that if I **absolutely** have to. Note that Postgres is typically much better (faster) with complicated queries then MySQL. So don't be afraid of joining many tables. Only if you see that this **really** gives an unacceptable performance, then use tricks like that.

Comment: Thanks, I also think that this type of calculation is troublesome but I was curious anyway and wanted to try writing such trigger. Thanks.